# Use an external HDMI display to show the output

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!!

I would like to execute the rosrun command on my laptop and showing the turtlesim window on a external HDMI display by default, but I don't know how to do it. Is there any archive where I have to change the code for doing that?

I say the turtlesim as an example, I want to do the same in my project.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263644/use-an-external-hdmi-display-to-show-the-output/) by [Emilio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23551/emilio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Making a window spawn in a specific place isn't really related to ROS; it's something that should be handled by your GUI library (QT, GTK, Wx, etc).

I don't think turtlesim has any arguments to make it spawn in a particular place.

Since this is for your project, and not turtlesim, you should probably ignore the turtlesim GUI and focus on your project (or a small app that uses the same windowing library)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0